Proxmox server connection to itself
Proxmox server connection problem
Hello,
I have a proxmox server with 3 vm to simplify:

Reverse proxy nginx (www.exemple.com and dev.exemple.com)
Apache 2 + php (www.exemple.com)
Apache 2 + php (dev.exemple.com)

The proxmox server is configured with a NAT to route connections from ports 80 and 443 to the reverse proxy.
Then the reverse proxy dispatches the requests to the apache backends.
I have a problem with the requests between the servers. I would like to use the prestashop migration pro module.
But the connection is not made between the two sites.
After investigation it appears that the vm as well as the proxmox server cannot access https://www.exemple.com/modules/migrationproserver/server.php nor https://www.exemple.com/
I checked the dns, it is consistent with the server's ip address.
a curl from another server works:
C:\> curl -v https://www.exemple.com/modules/migrationproserver/server.php
* Host www.exemple.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443...
* Connected to www.exemple.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /modules/migrationproserver/server.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.exemple.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.9.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.22.1
< Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2024 12:33:20 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: 5a2c67b4928ffe5745bb882ad7942d17=XwDTzVCEzzMm3UA4vOLuv81xMCyKsabetDswldDY8yZL1JIpYMBkBPzSX%2Fq2BoRQHDovD6KycOnENbvlEbFRHxsE%2FVkDK36BNwxFdNgMhHw%3D000075; expires=Wed, 11-Dec-2024 12:33:20 GMT; Max-Age=1728000; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; domain=www.exemple.com; httponly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
<
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiJlcnJvciIsIm1lc3NhZ2UiOiJUaGUgYnJpZGdlIGNvbm5lY3RvciBtb2R1bGUgZ2VuZXJhdGVkIGZvciBkZXYuc2VudGllci1uYXR1cmUuZnIhIFBsZWFzZSwgZG93bmxvYWQgYWdhaW4gYnJpZGdlIGNvbm5lY3RvciBtb2R1bGUgYW5kIGluc3RhbGwgdG8gdGhlIFNvdXJjZSBzaG9wIChvbGQgc2hvcCkgYW5kIHRyeSBjb25uZWN0aW9uIGFnYWluLiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOm51bGx9* Connection #0 to host www.exemple.com left intact

but not from the proxmox server for example:
root@px1:~# curl -i -v https://www.exmple.com/modules/migrationproserver/server.php
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443...
* connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 443 failed: Connexion refusée
* Failed to connect to www.exemple.com port 443 after 10 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.exemple.com port 443 after 10 ms: Couldn't connect to server

It works by going through the private address of the VM by specifying the domain name so that nginx redirects to the right backend:
root@px1:~# curl -v -k -H "Host: www.exemple.com" https://192.168.0.2/modules/migrationproserver/server.php
*   Trying 192.168.0.2:443...
* Connected to 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=dev.exemple.com
*  start date: Nov  2 13:11:32 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 31 13:11:31 2025 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=E6
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET /modules/migrationproserver/server.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.exemple.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.22.1
< Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2024 13:30:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: 5a2c67b4928ffe5745bb882ad7942d17=XwDTzVCEzzMm3UA4vOLuv%2ByNk%2F9eC0XevBxQW1yr%2FDRL1JIpYMBkBPzSX%2Fq2BoRQHDovD6KycOnENbvlEbFRHxy4Q2cfWeX46zjsvWshXK4%3D000075; expires=Wed, 11-Dec-2024 13:30:28 GMT; Max-Age=1728000; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; domain=www.exemple.com; httponly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.2 left intact
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiJlcnJvciIsIm1lc3NhZ2UiOiJUaGUgYnJpZGdlIGNvbm5lY3RvciBtb2R1bGUgZ2VuZXJhdGVkIGZvciBkZXYuc2VudGllci1uYXR1cmUuZnIhIFBsZWFzZSwgZG93bmxvYWQgYWdhaW4gYnJpZGdlIGNvbm5lY3RvciBtb2R1bGUgYW5kIGluc3RhbGwgdG8gdGhlIFNvdXJjZSBzaG9wIChvbGQgc2hvcCkgYW5kIHRyeSBjb25uZWN0aW9uIGFnYWluLiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOm51bGx9root@px1:~#

but however it talks about the dev certificate and not www.
I'm a little lost, it may be a NAT problem since it works from outside the proxmox server ...
There is the configuration of the NAT :
root@px1:~# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:192.168.0.2:80
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:192.168.0.2:443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

The issue here seems to be that you're unable to connect to the proxy from the inside network due to a NAT issue.
It happens the same with firewalls and inside clients unable to connect to the VPN listening on the public IP of the firewall itself.
It should be possible to workaround this issue if you specify in each webserver's host file the hostname and private ip address of the other webserver VM. Let's assume the following:

dev.example.com VM IP: 192.168.x.y

www.example.com VM IP: 192.168.x.z


The configuration you need to do:

in www.example.com VM /etc/hosts file add a row: 192.168.x.y dev.example.com

in the dev.example.com VM /etc/hosts file add a row: 192.168.x.z www.example.com example.com


This way the VMs should be able to connect to each other's website without the need to use the proxmox server public network nor the nginx proxy, given the two webserver VMs are both on the same virtual network.
Also this won't affect the networking nor the ability of the two webservers to serve their pages via the nginx proxy. I really think this is the cleanest possible solution, and if example.com is already in production you don't risk of messing up with the networking configuration and consequent downtime.

Hello and thank you for your answer.
I tried but it doesn't work. It's apparently not a hostname problem

if you used the internal network's VMs IPs and it doesn't work, it means the two VMs are not on the same private network. it was one of my assumptions in the answer. doublecheck u did exactly as I said because I have a very similar proxmox setup in-lab, I could reproduce the issue on my side and the solution fixes the problem.
